# get the Id of the Text angular tatextElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, textangular

I am new to the `angularjs`. I am using a `textangular` for showing the HTML document. My code is

**HTML**

```
<div text-angular  class="html-editor-container textcontent-modal" id="originalDocumentId" spellcheck="false" ng-hide="fetchingDocumentAsHTML"
       ng-model="data.originalDocument" ta-disabled="true">
    </div>
```

Now, From this, I am getting the HTML document in my div. When I checked using the Web Developer tool that time It is showing the `taTextElement123344455` as a div for the content, now I want to get that div so that I can perform some another operation on the content.

SO I tried by doing `document.getElementById("taTextElement123344455")` But this Id is always changing. So, Can anyone please tell me how to get that div?

Comment: select with class instead, am sure it doesn't change

Comment: yes but which class ? Because when I checked for that div then <div id="taTextElement4637297511598757" ta-bind="ta-bind" ng-model="html" ta-readonly="disabled" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ta-bind ta-readonly">  this gives

Comment: why not this one `ta-readonly` if you don't have many element like this

Comment: I have many ta-readOnly and thing is that with class it is not working properly